# angularjs ng-repeat with Filter or ng-if condition

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to render text if it is Name or Value. I don't want to loop if it is createdate or enventId. I'm trying with Filter and ng-if condition. It is not working.

**HTML CODE**

```
  <tr ng-repeat="event in events | filter:Name ">
     <td >{{event.Name}} : </td>
     <td>{{ event.Value }}</td>
  </tr>
```

**JS CODE**

```
Events: [
    {
      CreatedTime: "/Date(1420757322810-0800)/",
      EventId: 13,
      Name: "AdGroupId",
      Value: "2367898"
    },

    {
      CreatedTime: "/Date(1420757322810-0800)/",
      EventId: 13,
      Name: "AdGroupId",
      Value: "2367898"
    }
]
```

I expect the result should be

AdGroupId :2367898

Comment: So you want to suppress events without a name property, right?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Just remove your filter and simply loop through "event in events", you can then choose to only render Name and Value in your html as you currently do

Comment: Why? I'm having 100's of events. I don't want repeat the loop if it is not name/value. I want to add condition.

Comment: What do you mean "if it is not name/value"? Do you mean "if it does not _have_ a name or value"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that what you are trying to ask is how to exclude items with neither a name nor a value, you'll need a custom function for this. This should suffice:

```
$scope.filterEvents = function(e){
    return e.Name || e.Value;
};
```

And then:

```
<tr ng-repeat="event in events | filter:filterEvents">
  <td >{{event.Name}} : </td>
  <td>{{ event.Value }}</td>
</tr>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/584bqcno/)

Alternatively, if you are saying you want to filter the values based on a specified name and/or value, you can do so like this:

```
$scope.filterEvents = function (e) {
    return ($scope.Name || $scope.Value) && 
           (!$scope.Name || $scope.Name === e.Name) && 
           (!$scope.Value || $scope.Value === e.Value);
};
```

(HTML is same as above)

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2tn4oqoa/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking for a filter to cut out the Events that has no Name and Value properties in it.

Here is a sample for you:

Controller:

```
$scope.filterNameValue = function(e){
    if(angular.isDefined(e.Name) && angular.isDefined(e.Value)) 
       return e;
  };
```

Html

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="event in events | filter: filterNameValue">
       <td >{{event.Name}} : </td>
       <td>{{ event.Value }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[Working Sample here](http://plnkr.co/edit/wPN9vnzWOxGiO0xkfZam)